# Asus EeePC X101CH Touchpad issue

Tags: drivers, touchpad, asus-laptop

I have an Asus EeePC X101CH that the touchpad was uninstalled from (I saw the uninstall dialog boxes open). After a restart there was a PS/2 mouse under  View Hidden Devices in Device Manager that wasn't installed properly (I'm assuming that this is the touchpad). Going to the Asus website and downloading the [drivers](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=20&s=1&m=Eee%20PC%20X101CH&os=29&hashedid=UrYgCG9yU9Yf92Qy) (V15.3.27.1), I get the error message "Synaptics device not found!".

I tried the other driver Version  v9.1.7.7 for the Sentelic TouchPad as well (when run it appears to be the driver for the finger sensing) and got the error message "This driver version is inapplicable for the touch pad. Please check the devices on the system and install the suitable driver.".

What's my next step?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had a nose about and managed to find a working installer that wasn't looking for specific hardware on my X101CH.

If you go to `Touchpad_Synaptics-V15_3_27_1/WinWDF/x86/` and run `dpinst.exe` as an administrator, that will guide you through the classic synaptics installer, and do all the hard work for you.
No manual installation should be needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install it manually via the device manager.

1. Download the Driver
2. Go to Device Manager
3. Select Ps/2 Mouse
4. Select Update Driver
5. Point the driver to the downloaded driver

That's it!